# Center a view up to a barrier

Tags: android, view, android-constraintlayout

Using Android views, I've stumbled upon a recurring issue and thought it was about time to ask if anyone has a solution.

I have a parent ConstraintLayout, the blue one in the picture.
This layout contains two views: a green view constrained to the left of the parent, and the red view constrained to the center of the parent.
Both red view and green view are text views, and their actual size may vary depending on the language.

[image]

My wish is for the red view to always stay centered, so to grow symmetrically left and right until it reaches the green view. At its maximum width, the red view will touch the green view on the left, and there will be empty space on the right of the same width as the width of the green view.

Problem is that I can't find a way **using regular XML layouts** to do it. I can think of several hacks to do it, but thinking there should be a clean way.

Any idea?

Comment: if you textview doesn't have a bg, you can keep it aligned to green and can use text's property of align to center instead of layout

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but just an idea, maybe you can try to add two more barriers. One at the  end of the green box at left. And one for it's symmetric. Because you said

> and there will be empty space on the right of the same width as the
> width of the green view

So with these two barriers you can mark the borders of the red one.

And you can set the constraints of the red to the barriers, and with 0dp width may work. Let us know :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the width of the red view will not ever need to go to two lines because it runs out of space (maybe it is truncated, marque'd or ellipsised) then you would simply constrain the start and end of the red view to a guideline set in the center of the *ConstraintLayout*.

However, if you can't guarantee that the red view will never need two lines then you are stuck with a hack. The simplest hack would be to create an invisible view on the right that has the same width as the green view. (It could simply be another *TextView* with the same text and characteristics.) You would then constrain the start of the red view to the end of the green view and the end to the start of the invisible view.